# How can I disable a thread with an onClickListener?

Tags: android, onclicklistener, splash-screen

I am working on this splash screen test and implemented a click listener to the layout so it can be skipped by clicking on the screen. The problem is that the intent is called twice, because the Loading thread is not properly interrupted when the screen is clicked. What am I doing wrong and how to avoid this error?

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {
    final Thread Loading = new Thread();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);
    ImageView SplashScreenView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.SplashScreenAnimation);
    SplashScreenView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.flashscreenanimation);
    AnimationDrawable SplashScreenAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) SplashScreenView.getBackground();
    SplashScreenAnimation.start();
    RelativeLayout OnTouchSkipScreen = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.SplashScreenView);
    OnTouchSkipScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Loading.interrupt();
            Loading.isInterrupted();
            Intent SplashScreen = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, HomeScreen.class);
            startActivity(SplashScreen);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            finish();
        }
    });
    Thread Loading = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(2573);
                Intent SplashScreen = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, HomeScreen.class);
                startActivity(SplashScreen);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                finish();
            }
        }
    };
    Loading.start();
}
}
```

Comment: Why there is two Loading thread in your code?

Comment: If you check your code you can see you have declared `final Thread Loading = new Thread();` twice.

Comment: make   'final Thread Loading ;' and if problem persists then make a Boolean variable and set its value to true 'onClick' and check for value false before startActivity in 'run()'

Comment: @Kartik_Agarwal I tried the boolean variable just like you said but the intent is called twice. How can I persist data for the boolean true onclick result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for it

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {
    Thread Loading ;
    boolean flag = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);
        ImageView SplashScreenView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.SplashScreenAnimation);
        SplashScreenView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bontactbook);
        AnimationDrawable SplashScreenAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) SplashScreenView.getBackground();
        SplashScreenAnimation.start();
        RelativeLayout OnTouchSkipScreen = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.flashscreenanimation);
        OnTouchSkipScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                flag = false;
                Intent SplashScreen = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, HomeScreen.class);
                startActivity(SplashScreen);
                finish();
            }
        });
        Thread Loading = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(5000);
                    if (flag) {
                        Intent SplashScreen = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, HomeScreen.class);
                        startActivity(SplashScreen);
                        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };
        Loading.start();
    }
}
```